# What is Kylo Ren's relationship with Darth Vader?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, darth-vader, kylo-ren

If

> Han Solo

is Kylo Ren's father, then how is

> Darth Vader Kylo Ren's grandfather?

Comment: Did you saw the movie? Leia says a bunch of times that he is his son.

Comment: Because Han isn't capable of asexual reproduction.

Comment: Maybe you are just mistaken. Darth Vader (Anakin Skywalker) gave birth to both Luke and Leia. Leia + Han = Kylo

Comment: Leia is also anakin/vadar's daughter.

Comment: Clearly Han Solo is too awesome to breed with any creature not himself, and thus reproduces via parthenogenesis, thereby validating this question.

Answer (score 35):

Kylo Ren has two parents: Han Solo and Leia Organa.

Leia is the daughter of Anakin Skywalker/Darth Vader, making Kylo Ren the grandson of Anakin/Vader.

Leia refers to their son a number of times in conversation with Han.

> He met her eyes steadily. “We’ve lost our son, forever.”

> “Always,” she told him. “From the shadows, in the beginning, even before I realized what was happening, he was manipulating everything, pulling our son toward the dark side.

> “If you see our son,” Leia whispered, “bring him home.”

Comment: Don't leia or Han also say at some point "he has too much Vadar in him"?

Comment: Yes, Han says that.

Comment: Well, we can ultimately thank Padme for “having too much Vader in her” for Luke & Leia, and Kylo Ben.

Answer (score 22):

Because Darth Vader (aka Anakin Skywalker) is Leia's father.

And Kylo Ren

> Is also the son of Leia.

It takes two to tango.

Answer (score 15):

## Darth Vader is Kylo Ren's *maternal* grandfather.

A maternal grandparent is someone who is your mom's parent. Your *paternal* grandparents are your father's parents. Your mom's parents are your *maternal* grandparents.<sup>([source](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/paternal))</sup>

Another way of saying it is "my grandfather on my mother's side" (or maternal grandfather) vs "my grandfather on my father's side" (or paternal grandfather).

You are correct that Vader is *not* Kylo's *paternal* grandfather (as that whould be Han's dad, and Vader is *not* Han's dad), but Vader is still Kylo's *maternal* grandfather (as that would be Leia's dad, and Vader *is* Leia's dad<sup>1</sup>).

Here's a chart I made to help make it abundantly clear:

[image: Paint-made genealogic tree]

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> We know Vader is Leia's father from *Return of the Jedi*, when Luke learns that Leia is his twin sister.</sub>

> LUKE: Leia's my sister!
>
> KENOBI: Your insight serves you well.